# Regenerate launcher application Icons

Tags: 16.04, launcher

I've installed spotify via:

```
sudo snap install spotify
```

I can find the Spotify Icon available on the search but not on my launcher, is there anyway I can regenerate the application icons (and names) if possible so I can see the icon on the Launcher.